# mssql function won't stop in node

Tags: node.js

I created a mssql DB query function file for my project and the following function won't stop.

After few checks, I can tell that the function return a valid value and the program keep running.

After a while I understood/think than the sql connection is still open after returning the value.

function file:

```
module.exports.dbquery = function (query){
    var sql = require('mssql')
    var config = {
        user:'user',
        password:'pass',
        server:'hostname',
        database:'DB'
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        sql.connect(config, function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            }
            var request = sql.Request()
            request.query(query, function(err, recordset){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                table = recordset.recordsets[0]
                resolve(table)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

How to close the connection or other wise what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can close the connection after the query if you wish, I'm using the Promisified interface on mssql (I think it's a little easier to read!).

```
module.exports.dbquery = function (query) {
    var sql = require('mssql')
    var config = {
        user:'user',
        password:'pass',
        server:'hostname',
        database:'DB'
    }

    return sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request().query(query).then(result => {
            pool.close();  // Close pool after query.
            return result;
        });
    });
}
```

or using async/await

```
module.exports.dbquery = async function (query) {
    var sql = require('mssql')
    var config = {
        user:'user',
        password:'pass',
        server:'hostname',
        database:'DB'
    }

    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
    let result = await pool.request().query(query);
    pool.close(); // Close connection.
    return result;
}
```

This will not keep the Node.js process running.